# Package missing when I run `sudo apt install ...`

Tags: apt, software-installation

I use Ubuntu 16.04. APT cannot seem to find the package `m4`:

```
root@kevin:/# sudo apt install m4

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package m4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'm4' has no installation candidate
```

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get update
```

This didn't make any difference.

```
root@kevin:/# grep main /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
# deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: It's funny... I use 16.04 lts and m4 is already installed, and it's not obsolete...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `grep main /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I see `root@kevin:/# sudo apt install m4`, so already root so no need for `sudo`...

Comment: yes , lol . It doesn't matter , problem is same @George

Comment: @kevin I know it does't matter but seems to me to be too worrisome for the system... :).

Answer (score 7):

Your `sources.list` doesn't contain any binary sources.

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and enable all sources at the first tab.

Then the system will suggest to update and you'll be able to install everything from the repos.

Comment: awesome! it works !! Thank you very much! oh it has wasted much of my time! @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

Your command `sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get update` does not have the necessary second `sudo` after the `&&`, so apt doesn't have the privileges it needs in order to update properly.

Please run `sudo apt update`. Then you should be able to install m4.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason here - the OP appears to be running the commands from a root shell, so `sudo` is moot (otherwise there'd be an error about permissions / lock files)

Comment: Good point. Then I have no idea what's going on. @kevin , it would be helpful if you tell us what appears on the screen when you run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: root@kevin:/home/kevin# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin-abc/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial 
InRelease       
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Comment: Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.                                                                                                 sorry , I can't paste all the content in one box @Nick Weinberg

Comment: Problem has been solved , My sources.list doesn't contain any binary sources. Thanks for your help as well!